# Subprocess opening new cmd window when using "runas"

Tags: python, windows, cmd, subprocess, runas

I want to use subprocess with cmd.exe like shown below, but just run as a different user. The code shown below will pop open a cmd process in the background that I can later interact with

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe')
```

However, when I user runas like this, it will run cmd.exe, but rather than popping it open in the background, it will open an entirely new window, how would I avoid this?

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('runas /user:user2 /savecred cmd.exe')
```

Comment: As long as you need `runas` I see no way to avoid it. You are starting the `runas` executable, but it is `runas` who creates the separate process.

Comment: In the first example, cmd.exe is not waiting in the background at all. If run from python.exe, it's actively competing with python.exe to access the console, which is a mess if your program depends on reading from the console.

Comment: I doubt that it is possible for two processes belonging to different users to share a console.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, users at the same or greater integrity level as the conhost.exe instance can attach to it -- at least in Windows 10; I haven't checked Windows 7. You can even do this with runas.exe if you run an intermediate pythonw.exe process that runs the following -c command-line script: `script = r"import ctypes, subprocess; ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32').AttachConsole(%d); subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe')" % (os.getpid(),)`.

Comment: But see my earlier comment for why I think this is dubious. It could maybe be made sane by calling `CreateProcessWithLogonW` instead of using runas.exe. Have the launcher pythonw.exe process wait on the target process, so the original parent can wait on the launcher. That way the target won't compete with the original parent for access to the console.

Comment: @eryksun: I stand corrected, though as you say Windows 7 may be different.  (If I remember correctly, it was Windows 8 that started using real handles for the console rather than pseudohandles?)  I'd have thought consoles would need to remain isolated for security reasons, but I guess having a potentially malicious process attach to your console is no different in principle to a shatter attack against a GUI application.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, the secondary logon service adds the `NT Authority\LogonSessionId_X` security principal for the interactive session to the new token, which grants access to the `WindowStation` and `Desktop` and is probably checked by conhost.exe, in addition to checking the integrity level, in the implementation of `AttachConsole`. I could be wrong, but I don't think using kernel handles (for `\Device\ConDrv`) instead of ALPC (Windows 7) for IPC between the client and conhost.exe has any bearing on the problem, but switching from csrss.exe (Vista) to instances of conhost.exe probably did.